# Best way to setup apach default site

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, httpd.conf

I'm working on setting up a web hosting system and was wondering what the best way to configure the default configuration is to look in a folder if there is no vhost for it.

Here's how I would like it setup:

```
site1.com vhost setup and serves from files /home/site1.com/public_html/ (already working)
site2.com no vhost serves the files from /home/hosted/site2.com/public_html/
site3.com no vhost serves the files from /home/default/public_html because  /home/default/site3.com/public_html does not exist. (already working)
1.1.1.1 serves files from /home/default/public_html (already working)
```

The question I have is how to make site2.com work. Should it be a .htaccess in home/default/public_html or something in the default config file?

Comment: NameBased Virtual Hosting is your friend.

Comment: Which is how site1.com is setup. I was wanting to not have to setup those for every site in an attempt to automate the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the Apache [`Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/mass.html) which contains a number of directives that may be of use to you.

Comment: Hadn't seen that one. That was what I was looking for. Thanks.